# magento flickr gallery extension - how to get image descriptions?

Tags: magento, flickr

I installed this flickr extension https://github.com/srka/Srka-Magento-Flickr-Gallery and I am trying to load the description for each image. Can someone advise on how to get each image description?

I looked at flickr.photos.getInfo but I have no idea how to implement this. The image titles load but not the description? :/